# Grails and Spring Security UI - no dropdown menu

Tags: grails, configuration, spring-security

I've got a problem with grails spring-security-ui plugin. I was following all the instruction in docs (http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui) but I can't get visibile dropdown menus and login in management console.

[Link to example screen](http://postimage.org/image/9eidwyuc9/)

I'm new to Grails and Groovy so please don't shout if answer is very simple :)

Any help will be appreciated!

Some config of my app:

**Grails**: 2.1.1 
**Installed modules**:
logging - 2.1.1 
core - 2.1.1
i18n - 2.1.1
dataSource - 2.1.1
codecs - 2.1.1
servlets - 2.1.1
groovyPages - 2.1.1
resources - 1.1.6
springSecurityUi - 0.2
jquery - 1.8.0
databaseMigration - 1.1
mail - 1.0
famfamfam - 1.0.1
tomcat - 2.1.1
webxml - 1.4.1
urlMappings - 2.1.1
controllers - 2.1.1
domainClass - 2.1.1
jqueryUi - 1.8.15
hibernate - 2.1.1
mimeTypes - 2.1.1
services - 2.1.1
converters - 2.1.1
validation - 2.1.1
filters - 2.1.1
scaffolding - 2.1.1
springSecurityCore - 1.2.7.3
cache - 1.0.0

Comment: Anyone? So maybe some tutorials, examples of good configuration of spirng-security-ui? I've already found this: http://ajibrans.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/spring-security-plugin-with-grails-1-3-7/ but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to upgrade to version 1.8.24 of jQuery UI.

Comment: Yes, I've solve this issue in this way and completely forgot to post answer ;). Thanks for this!